# How to use one maven dependency for JUnit tests and another dependency for the build?

Tags: maven, junit, jenkins, scope, simulator

I am facing a situation, where I thought that Maven offers me the correct tools.
Either I am wrong or Maven ;o)

Seriously.

We are writing software to work with a 3rd party lib, let's call it prod.jar. This lib needs an environment that can connect to the prod.jar servers.
Obviously, our Jenkins is not and cannot be set up in this way. Thus, when running the tests with the prod.jar, everything will fail, as no connection can be set up.

My idea was to write a simulator that behaves like the real prod.jar and can be used for unit tests, called simulator.jar. Both, the prod.jar and the simulator.jar hold the same packages with the same class names. They only do differ in functionality. I have done this, to enable development and to cover as much on JUnit side on Jenkins. Of course, we also do test against the prod.jar, but not with Jenkins.

So what I did is to create two eclipse projects:

- prod-code: with a pom.xml that has prod.jar as a dependency
- simulator-code: with a pom.xml that has the simulator.jar as a dependency

So depending on which project you add as a dependency to the main project, either the simulator or the prod code are used. That works fine.

But then we get the error that the build contains the wrong jar.

How can I set up maven, if possible, so that I can use always the same pom, but maybe with different mvn parameters, to use the simulator during the test process and to use the prod code during the build process.

I tried with maven profiles, but when using the build jar, it will complain.

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>simulator</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>main-project</groupId>
                <artifactId>simulator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>jenkins</id>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>main-project</groupId>
                <artifactId>simulator</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>main-project/groupId>
                <artifactId>prod</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>realSystem</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>main-project</groupId>
                <artifactId>prod</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Any help appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to have a test build, and a production build, yet there are 3 profiles shown.  Please help me understand why.

Comment: Using maven for this purpose smells like problems (apart from the question whether it can be done this way at all), feels like you're trying to solve this problem on the wrong abstraction level. You should consider using Dependency Injection for your components so you can use mock ("simulated") imlpementations in the tests.